# How do I use .htaccess to hide a folder and extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to be able to type “example.com/page” in the url and my browser to load “example.com/folder/page.php”

I literally looked at 10+ video tutorials and 20+ pages on how to do this and none of them are working properly. I can't include everything I've tried because I've tried so many with none of them working.

An explanation would also be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# it may also need to set mutliviews
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless PHP URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```